# "spoon up" someone's nose

Tags: slang, lyrics, reference

IMO, English songs from 80 to early 00 were golden.

Anyway, I don't know how many time I listened to [**Billy Joel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Joel)'s songs.

One of his songs [**Big Shot**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEea624OBzM) has this line,

> Well, you went uptown
> Ridin' in your limousine
> With your fine Park Avenue clothes
> You had the Dom Perignon
> In your hand
> And the **spoon up your nose**
> Ooh, and when you
> Wake up in the mornin'
> With your head on fire
> And your eyes too bloody to see
> Go on and cry in your coffee
> But don't come bitchin' to me

To "spoon up", the idiom according to [**this dictionary**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spoon+up), says,

> To serve something (to someone) with a spoon or ladle. A noun or pronoun can be used between "spoon" and "up."

By this definition, I have no idea what "spoon up someone's nose" means.

Comment: Billy Joel is American, not English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I said it in "generally speaking", meaning including British songs such as Spice Girls. Billi just happened to be an American.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Or Limhal. His song for Never Ending Story recently reanimated in the States. Every songs are "English".

Comment: Limahl comes from my wife's home town. She says she thinks he is ridiculous, but, I have noticed, she sings along to that song when it comes on the car radio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are asking about, "the spoon up your nose", is not the same as "to spoon up". Here "spoon" is a noun, and the lyrics go "You had the Dom Perignon in your hand / And the spoon up your nose". Calling someone a big shot indicates that person considers themself important and other people don't necessarily agree. It has a strong negative implication that the person being called a "big shot" has too much [self-conceit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-conceit), is [self-important](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-important), [too big for their britches](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/too-big-for-your-britches).

Here the person being accused is a dummy "you", a placeholder for anyone the song is directed at. "You" are too smug and that is evidenced by "you" having a Dom Perignon in "your" hand and (having) a spoon up "your" nose. [Dom Pérignon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom_P%C3%A9rignon) is a pricey brand of Champagne.

"Having a spoon up one's nose" is a euphemism for doing drugs, referring to people using a spoon to snort cocaine. Powder cocaine has been considered a more expensive drug for the upper-middle class, compared to crack cocaine, methamphetamine, and other drugs.